# Attaching a file as a field on a record

Tags: custom-field, page-layout, custom-link

Is there a way to allow a user to attach a file to a field on a record?

For example, I have a custom Survery page layout (using Survey__c custom object) that displays fields for the user to populate. I would like the user to attach a document/s to one of the fields (let's call it Proof__c) on the page layout.

[image: Attached Document Field]

Comment: Can you describe your scenario more precisely? What do you mean by **attach**? Why that can not be done on record level?

Comment: just added an illustration - want user to be able to click on the field and upload the document - one document only, I want the document link to be stored directly in the field as opposed to a related list.

Comment: You will very likely need a custom Visualforce UI for this functionality.

Comment: The only place I know you can do this without VF is on a KnowledgeArticle as it has a field type of attachment, I doubt that will help you though...